# If SEO is that important and vital for businesses, then why Microsoft, Sony, LG etc. are not in the first page at all?

Tags: seo

I know they already are famous. But they do have users using and coming back to their websites every hour, in millions, so wouldn't thins bring them to the first page?

what is the secret behind these giants that from one hand, they are not in the first page, and from the other hand, they rank very high in sales and business numbers? anybody can explain?

Comment: Questions on this site are required to about a [website under your own control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), otherwise we'd just be speculating.

Answer (score 3):

1. Microsoft has approx 914,818 organic keywords. If you were to buy this traffic, it would cost 289.7M. [Source](https://www.spyfu.com/overview/domain?query=microsoft.com)
2. Sony gets 4.1M worth of organic traffic, and ranks for a total of approximately 80,868 words. [source](https://www.spyfu.com/overview/domain?query=sony.com)

I'm going to stop here. One thing you must realize is that these brands are household names, and their exposure organically is efficacious and extremely hard to pass-up for any old "brand."